# Flask Socket io/ Audio stream decoding problem with filed received in python server

Tags: python, html, audio, flask-socketio, recordrtc

thanks for reading this post. I've been working on a project that takes in audio input from client side and emit the recorded audio to python server for analyzation. I've encountered a problem decoding what is being emitted from the client/write the received audio data into new wav file on server side.

Below is the client side code:

```
  recordAudio = RecordRTC(stream, {
              type: 'audio',
              mimeType: 'audio/wav',
              sampleRate: 44100, 
              audioBitsPerSecond : 256 * 8 * 1024,
              recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder, 
              numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
              timeSlice: 4000,
              desiredSampRate: 16000
          });

  recordAudio.stopRecording(function() {
         // after stopping the audio, get the audio data
              recordAudio.getDataURL(function(audioDataURL) {
                  var files = {
                      audio: {
                          type: recordAudio.getBlob().type || 'audio/wav',
                          dataURL: audioDataURL
                      }
                  };
                  socketio.emit('wav', files);
              });
          });
      };
```

I thought I would be able to retrieve audio data (for writeframes method) from the dataurl, however it returns to be a string. After searching online, I figured it might be the encoded string that I would need to decode into array buffers?　At this point I'm fairly confused.

Server-side:

```
@socketio.on('wav')
def handle_wav(files):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    print('file received')
    //how to get audio data from files to write it as new wav file? 
    waveFiles = files['audio']['dataURL'] // str 
    #decoded_data = base64.b64decode(waveFiles) // throws error
    wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(1)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
    wf.setframerate(44100)
    wf.writeframes(decoded_data)
    wf.close()
```

Thank you in prior for your time!

---

Answer (score 0):

The `urllib` package can open Data URIs:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

f = urlopen(data_url)
decoded_data = f.read()
```

Comment: Hi, Miguel thanks for answering,  I tried the solution, however there's something wrong with my client-server connection where Although I've set the CORs to = "*", however on my server console I started to get these and the server stopped receiving the recorded audio file from client side

Comment: My client Index.html stop refreshing content from the server although it runs on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and does record a file, however I can't received it anymore where as when I posted the question I could

Comment: I don't know. You are asking a completely different question, now, and I have no context to answer it. The log that you pasted shows no errors.

Comment: Hi, Miguel, turns out I accidentally saved the index.html twice under different folders.